# sftp from Unix server to Window

Tags: sftp, window

I am trying to `sftp` from a Unix box to my computer. I'm use the command:

```
sftp userid@ipaddr
```

where "ipaddr" is the IP Address of my computer. But I'm unable to connect.

I tried with `ftp` and `sftpg3`, but I'm getting this error `Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer`.

How can I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 7):

First, we see some information from `man sftp`:

```
DESCRIPTION
     sftp is an interactive file transfer program, similar to ftp(1), which
     performs all operations over an encrypted ssh(1) transport.  It may also
     use many features of ssh, such as public key authentication and compres‐
     sion.  sftp connects and logs into the specified host, then enters an
     interactive command mode.
```

`sftp` do all thing over `ssh`, so if you want to use `sftp`, you must have a successful `ssh` connection, in this case, your local machine is a `ssh client` and remote machine is `ssh server`.

By default, `Windows` machines do not have a `ssh server`, so you can not use `sftp` with them. You must have a `ssh server` software install in `Windows` machine, like [winsshd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd).

Answer (score 0):

SFTP entails communication between two pieces of software. Your `sftp` command is the client, but there needs to be server software running at the other end as well as network connectivity between you.

Doesn't look like standard Windows ships with SFTP server - the closest is simple FTP in XP Professional.

There are many third-party options however, including free ones. [CoreFTP's mini sftp server](http://www.coreftp.com/server/download/msftpsrvr.exe) is a personal favourite for simplicity. [Filezilla Server](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) probably wins popularity-wise as the solid (and open-source) choice.

Regarding connectivity, you need to make sure the relevant ports are open at both ends, firewalls allow the traffic, and network configuration (port forwarding etc.) allows communication.

Comment: FTP Server in Windows XP: http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1491&page=2

Comment: In-depth discussion of network configuration: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration